# Oracle IDOC option list localization

Tags: oracle, webcenter, idoc

I've been stuck on this issue for a while now and google is of little help. I'm trying to localize values within an option list for a form. IDOC components I've plugged into have only gotten me so far, so I'm turning to helpful people here. What do I have to do to pass option list values through lc(), then display these values as captions for a drop-down ?

Comment: What does your initial code look like?

You probably have a ResultSet you can loop over and then call the Idoc Script function lc() on each of the values.

Comment: The initial code is the core code with very little changes. I've been looking for something like you described, yet my search has come up empty, thus I'm turning to stackoverflow

Comment: If you can point to a gist, then I can help you better decipher what to do. It should be fairly straightforward (loop and call lc).